# Can't get text from html page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fetch, xss

I have the page: https://www.petedge.com/tp-cat-grooming-bag#sku_id=TP463%2017
Which when you hover over the ratings you get a popup with the text "3.5 out of 5"
[image]

I need to get this text "3.5 out of 5" but I have not been able to do it after trying two different methods:

**method1: get it from the page body**
The text is inside an iframe:
[image]

If I try to get the iframe body contents with javascript I get hit with a cross-origin err:
[image]
I think this is because the iframe src is from a different url.

Is there any way I can get this rating txt in my chrome console dev tools window using javascript?
I have been trying to use code like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
function receiver(e) {
    console.log("e3=",e.currentTarget[3]);
}
function update_child() {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[1];
    el.contentWindow.postMessage('Updated from parent', '*');
}
```

This code detect when I hover over the iframe but I can't use it to print the inner text contents.

**method2: fetch request**
If I visit the URL: https://widget.trustpilot.com/trustbox-data/577258fb31f02306e4e3aaf9?businessUnitId=5c53658de78c440001024900&locale=en-US&sku=TP463%2CTP463%2017%2CTP463%2018%2CTP463%2019

In my browser I get the info I need, I have been trying to make a fetch request to this site but no luck either as my code:

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://widget.trustpilot.com/trustbox-data/577258fb31f02306e4e3aaf9?businessUnitId=5c53658de78c440001024900&locale=en-US&sku=TP463%2CTP463%2017%2CTP463%2018%2CTP463%2019').then(response => {
  console.log("response=",response)
})
.then((data) => {
  console.log("data=",data)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log("error=",error)
})
```

Is never able to return data from that URL

Comment: The element that contains the desired text has an id. Does `document.querySelector("#product-info").innerText` not work?

Answer (score 0):

### Change your Javascript Context.

Above the console is a "Context" drop down. Normally it should say Top, for the top level document. Looking at your site there are several iframes with the same content, you may need to guess at which one it is. But you can change your context to the correct iframe and execute a selector normally from there. I've added an example below.

[image: JS Context Changed to popup.html]

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // my hacky approach:
function get_content() {
  var html = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = html.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
}
// Gabi's elegant approach, but eliminating one unnecessary line of code:
function gabi_content() {
  var element = document.getElementById('txt');
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText || element.textContent;
}
// and exploiting the fact that IDs pollute the window namespace:
function txt_content() {
  txt.innerHTML = txt.innerText || txt.textContent;
}
```

```css
.A {
  background: blue;
}

.B {
  font-style: italic;
}

.C {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="get_content()" value="Get Content (bad)" />
<input type="button" onclick="gabi_content()" value="Get Content (good)" />
<input type="button" onclick="txt_content()" value="Get Content (shortest)" />
<p id='txt'>
  <span class="A">I am</span>
  <span class="B">working in </span>
  <span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```